# How do I change the content of a view on MVC?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, pug

On MVC architecture,  do I use one template and update the content using JavaScript/ routes?  or Do I make multiple templates for each route?

Comment: I assume with templates you mean views. Typically if your model-data is not going to change on the page, then you can rely on json/ajax or postbacks. If your page consists of various chunks of markups with different model-data ( like usercontrols in asp.net web forms), then you should use partial views.